# How does one gets the jQuery UI layout plugin to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am willing to use the jQuery UI layout plugin ([layout.jquery-dev.net](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)) to make 2 resizable `<div>`. It would be just the `center` and `east` panels we can see [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html).

From the documentation I could make the simplest layout to work :

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var oOptions = {
      applyDefaultStyles: true
    };
    $('body').layout(oOptions);
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
  <div class="ui-layout-east">East</div>
</body>
```

But when I try my own thing (with both panels resizable by dragging the vertical divider), it stops working entirely.

```
var oOptions = {
  closable:         false,
  resizable:        true,
  slidable:         true,
  center__minWidth: 200,
  east__minSize:    200
};
```

I have no background in JavaScript and I might just be dumb asking here. But from what I understood when reading the `<script>` at the demo page ([same as above](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)), it should works fine with the `resizable` option only.

Comment: Could you add an [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) example?

Comment: It works in here though, http://jsfiddle.net/Q3VhJ/2/. Checking what could be different (using Django).

Comment: ... but cannot find anything. Works with `applyDefaultStyles`, doesn't anymore once I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.9.2 did the thing.

Comment: yes, I just tried to use jquery 2.x and there seems to be bugs with my center panel on a layout I was experimenting with